# Countdown timer get values

Tags: jquery, countdowntimer

I am playing around with a countdown timer. I created input fields to get the values and wrapped the jquery in a function that is called on button click.

Inside my function I did this:

```
var d = document.getElementById('#day').value;
```

etc.

Then in my countdown time, instead of the number I added the variable d for day but it does not work.

Can someone tell me how to have the jquery pull in the value from the user input?

Here is the codepen with the code: http://codepen.io/bskousen/pen/JoPVEB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
var d = document.getElementById('day').value;
```

or

```
var d = $('#day').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing everything almost right. The getElementById function takes only the string Id, though, without the hash sign!